# UWP - Enable loopback incoming connections

Tags: c#, tcp, server, uwp, loopback

I'm trying to create a simple TCP server using UWP application, but I cannot connect to this server on local machine using loopback. Until now, I have tried:

- Added capabilities: Internet (Client & Server), Internet (Client), Private networks
- Enabled loopback using CheckNetIsolation.exe in cmd
- Enabled loopback in VS 2017 project properties
- Enabled loopback using Enable AppContainer Loopback program (it shows that loopback has been enabled)

All of this have failed and I'm still not able to connect to the app. I'm still getting connection timeout while trying to connect via anything (web browser, custom app, telnet) Of course everything works ok while app is deployed to remote device. Using nestat shows that TCP port on 0.0.0.0 has been opened.

Comment: You cannot connect to loopback using Net Library.  Will get error that says will refuse 127.0.0.1.  Some people says it works so I suspect it has to do with the way localhost is defined in the file : C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.  So when connecting to a PC have the listener use IP.ANY and start first.  Then have client connect to PC IP address (not loopback).

Comment: Sadly, creating a new entry in host file (like 127.0.0.1 me.com) and using it doesn't work neither (ping works). I heard about people using virtual machines to run that, but still isn't that loopback connection essential for testing your app? This Microsoft...

Comment: This is the World of Microsoft, not necessarily reality.  But you can also blame the IEEE.  The IEEE RFC specifications have a lot options.  I'm not familiar with the Loopback requirements except for the fact that every device must have one at address 127.0.0.1.  But how it works I'm not sure.  I don't know if loopback means from the outside world, inside world, or both.  Microsoft has implemented an IP.Any for listening which I believe is really 127.0.0.1.  So once you are listening to 127.0.0.1 you can't also use for sending.

Comment: IP.Any is actually an 0.0.0.0 address. You can check it by running netstat -a at cmd while listening on any port. UWP just prohibits incoming connections (connections not actual data, you can establish an outgoing connection and send data in both ways) originating from address 127.0.0.1. Therefore you cannot create a UWP sever and test it locally. Sadly I don't understand why and why this cannot be overridden.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find out something new about this problem? unfortunately there is not much on internet ... I can understand security reason ecc... but at least for debug they should let us ablo to do it

Answer (score 0):

According to this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback, adding a normal loopback exemption is not enough to run server. You need to use this command: `CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -is -n=<AppContainer or Package Family>`.

> Unlike outbound connection configuration, inbound connections require CheckNetIsolation.exe to run continuously while the server application is receiving connections.